# ForEach requires that '[String : String]' conform to 'Identifiable'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I don't know how to write ForEach in Array in struct by SwiftUI.

```
struct Group: Identifiable,Decodable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var members: [[String:String]]
}
```

I want to display member's array by using `ForEach`.

```
 @ObservedObject var groupVM: GroupViewModel
  var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List{
                    ScrollView{
                        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading){
                            ForEach(groupVM.group.members){ member in
                                    groupMemberCell()
                            }
                        }
                     } 
                }    
             }
  }
```

I got this error `Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that '[String : String]' conform to 'Identifiable'`.

Please tell me how to write the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the value for `members` (of type `[[String: String]]`) does not automatically conform to `Identifiable`.

It depends on your model as to how each individual member (with data `[String: String]`) needs to be identified, as it's not clear from this dictionary how you would do this (a dictionary is a bunch of keys and values for each member, so how do we know which member is which based off this data?).

I'd suggest modelling each member as its own object and include a field that allows you to uniquely identify each member (such as having an `id` for each member, which could be their user id in your application for example).

```swift
struct Member: Identifiable, Decodable {
  var id: String
  var data: [String: String]
}
```

Your group would then look like:

```swift
struct Group: Identifiable, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var members: [Member]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Bradley. Thank you for quick response. I don't need `id` property in Member struct. So can I write this too. 
`struct Member:  Decodable,Hashable {
//  var id: String
  var data: [String: String]
}
`
`ForEach(groupVM.group.members,id: \.self){ member in
                                    groupMemberCell()
                            }
`
Thank you.

Comment: @ShunTakahashi You can do this too, but be aware that if you change the data at all you'll lose the "identity" of each member because the `id` is now based off all the data in the dictionary. This means SwiftUI won't be able to reason about which member is which when it comes to things like animations. Also if two members end up having the same data you may see glitches such as missing or duplicate members in your list!

Comment: @ShunTakahashi If there are no reasonable `id` to be given to the `Member`, you can also consider using a `UUID` type for `id`.